# Factorials and Powers calculator

Tags: beginner, haskell

I just started learning Haskell, and I made a simple program which can calculate factorials and powers:

Input:

```
What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) 1
Enter a number: 10
The factorial of 10 is: 3628800
What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) 2
Enter the base number: 2
Enter the exponent: 10
2^10 = 1024.0
What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) 0
```

The code is:

```
import System.IO
import System.Exit
import Control.Monad

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]

powerInternal :: Double -> Integer -> Double
powerInternal b 0 = 1
powerInternal b e = b * powerInternal b (e - 1)

power :: Double -> Integer -> Double
power b e = if e >= 0
  then powerInternal b e
  else 1 / powerInternal b (-e)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

  putStr "What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) "
  input <- getLine

  when (read input == 0) exitSuccess

  if read input == 1
    then do
    putStr "Enter a number: "
    hFlush stdout

    num <- getLine
    putStrLn ("The factorial of " ++ num ++ " is: " ++ show (factorial (read num)))
  else do
    putStr "Enter the base number: "

    base <- getLine
    putStr "Enter the exponent: "
    expe <- getLine

    putStrLn (base ++ "^" ++ expe ++ " = " ++ show (power (read base) (read expe)))

  main
```

I am looking for suggestions on how to improve the code, make it shorter, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The rise for power

Let's start with `powerInternal`. First of all, there's [a better algorithm for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) \$b^e\$, which takes \$\mathcal O(\log e)\$ instead of \$\mathcal O(e)\$:

$$b^e = \begin{cases}\left(b^2\right)^\frac{e}{2},&e~\text{even}\\
b\left(b^2\right)^\frac{e-1}{2},&e~\text{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Implementing this is left as an exercise. But it seems like you want to use `powerInternal` only in `power`, since it doesn't work with negative exponents. Therefore, you should reduce its scope:

```
power :: Double -> Integer -> Double
power b e = if e >= 0
    then powerInternal b e
    else 1 / powerInternal b (-e)
  where
    powerInternal :: Double -> Integer -> Double
    powerInternal b 0 = 1
    powerInternal b e = b * powerInternal b (e - 1)
```

However, we're reinventing the wheel. There's already a function of type

```
(Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

that supports negative exponents. It's called [`(^^)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94--94-). So we can change your `power` function:

```
power :: Double -> Integer -> Double
power b e = b ^^ e
-- or, shorter, but less readable
-- power = (^^)
```

This is probably the shortest variant you can get. Onwards

## Don't trust the user

```
What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) abc
Run.hs: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Users *will* provide wrong input. Either because they intended to do so, or because their finger slipped and they accidentally put `12` instead of `1`. If you don't want your program to crash, you probably want to ask again instead. Therefore, we should probably use a function:

```
askUser :: IO Int
askUser = do
  putStr "What do you want to do? (0: quit; 1: factorial; 2: power) "
  input <- getLine
```

We have now several ways to handle this. We could use `case`

```
  case input of
    "0" -> return 0
    "1" -> return 1
    "2" -> return 2
    _   -> putStrLn "Wrong input, please try again" >> askUser
```

but that's error prone. Instead, we use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`:

```
  let input' = readMaybe input

  if 0 <= input' && input' <= 2
     then return input'
     else putStrLn "Wrong input, please try again" >> askUser
```

We can shorten it if we use `fmap readMaybe getLine`:

```
askUser :: IO Int
askUser = do
  putStr "What do you want to do? (0: quit; 1: factorial; 2: power) "
  input <- fmap readMaybe getLine

  case input of
     Just x | 0 <= x && x <= 2 -> return x
     _                         -> putStrLn "Wrong input, please try again" >> askUser
```

Now we know that `askUser` will always return a number in the range 0-2.

## Foul magic

However, what's `0`? What is `1`? All three numbers are *magic numbers*, which is usually a code smell. You, as a developer, have to remember what a certain number stands for. Save them somewhere, like

```
userQuit, userFactorial, userPower :: Int
userQuit      = 0
userFactorial = 1
userPower     = 2
```

Now you can write

```
if answer == userQuit
```

instead of

```
if answer == 0
```

But aren't the choices of the user rather limited in comparison to `Int`? How about

```
data UserChoice = Quit | Factorial | Power deriving (Enum, Bounded, Show)
```

instead? Now we can use

```
askUserChoice :: IO UserChoice
askUserChoice = fmap toEnum askUser
```

to convert 0-2 to our own enumeration.

Now, with `askUserChoice`, we get the following main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

  input <- askUserChoice

  case input of
    Quit      -> exitSuccess
    Factorial -> userFactorial >> main
    Power     -> userPower     >> main
```

I will come to the yet unknown functions in a second. What did we gain so far? Well, `input` is going to be a valid answer when we try to inspect it, and we can pattern match on it. Even better, the compiler can tell us that we forgot a pattern if we decide to add `Addition` or something similar later.

## Splitting hairs and concerns

Now to the `user*` functions. They are pretty much the same as yours, with a small twist:

```
userFactorial :: IO ()
userFactorial = do
    num <- getInteger "a number"
    putStrLn ("The factorial of " ++ show num ++ " is: " ++ show (factorial num))    

userPower :: IO ()
userPower = do
    base <- getInteger "the base number"
    expe <- getInteger "the exponent"    
    putStrLn (show base ++ "^" ++ show expe ++ " = " ++ show (power base expe))
```

The twist is, that `getInteger` will ask the user till they actually provide an integer:

```
getInteger :: String -> IO Integer
getInteger what = do
    putStrLn ("Enter " ++ what ++ ": ")
    hFlush stdout

    input <- fmap readMaybe getLine

    case input of
      Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a number, please try again." >> getInteger what
      Just x  -> return x
```

## Summary

So, what has been improved?

1. The `power` function uses `(^^)`, a standard library function
2. We check user input for validity
3. We don't `read` values multiple times
4. We show our intentions for the user's action with a data type
5. We provide a succinct `main` and let other functions handle the actual work
6. We share common problems (getting an integer from the user) and don't repeat ourselfs.

From a beginners perspective, your code is fine, by the way. Some will tell you to use `($)` instead of parentheses in your `putStrLn` lines, but that's a personal preference. The only two *real* problems where the suboptimal `power`, and that you don't actually check user input.

## Bonus: Short alternative `main`

Well, the data type and so on is an overkill. We can check the initial decision a lot easier if we simply don't convert the result of `getLine` into a number (or another type):

```
main = do
  putStr "What do you want to do (0=quit, 1=factorial, 2=power) "
  input <- getLine

  case input of
    "0" -> exitSuccess
    "1" -> userFactorial >> main
    "2" -> userPower     >> main
    _   -> putStrLn "Wrong input, try again!" >> main
```

The key to getting `main` succinct here is still to split the code into another function. You can provide the code inline, but that's hardly readable anymore.

Comment: `-- or, shorter, but less readable
-- power = (^^)` I think it is more readable, I read it to mean that saying `power` is the same as using the `^^` infix function but in prefix form, at least conceptually. In practice (and on more complex cases) I agree that point-free can get less readable.

Comment: @Caridorc: Well, the "most readable" variant would probably just use `(^^)` instead of `power`, e.g. `printf "%f^%d = %f\n" base expe (base ^^ expe)`. ^^"

Comment: yes, defining a synonim is not needed (very comprehensive answer by the way, a sure +1 from me)